# Runned aws ecs task doesn't responde to request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I created simple docker image which sends 'Hello world!' when i send GET request to localhost.
Then i pushed it to ECR repo to aws. I already have default cluster with EC2 instance in it. I created task and launched it on this cluster. But when i follow public DNS link of EC2 instance, i don't get response. It uses default VPC.

I tried to create custom VPC with it's own security group but it didn't help me.

In task status i see 'RUNNING' but it doesn't work anyway.

What i need to do to make it work?

Comment: Did you opened the ports (80 and 443) in AWS VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have your application listen on another IP instead of listening on localhost?

Also consider security groups.
What do the logs show for your applicaton?